# How do I create a user read with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, crud

I'm using Rails, iOS, and devise. I want to read a single user. The path would be users/:id.

I get the following error:

```
Started GET "/users/0" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-11 17:37:50 -0600
Processing by UsersController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"0"}
[Devise] Could not find devise mapping for path "/users/0".
Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block? For example:

devise_scope :user do
  match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
end

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (Could not find devise mapping for path "/users/0".
Maybe you forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block? For example:

devise_scope :user do
  match "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
end
```

I've tried putting resources :users underneath devise_for :users as well as get "users/:id" => "users#show" and match "users/:id" => "users#show".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my final solution:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users"}

devise_scope :user do
  get "users/:id" => "users#show"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the section in the docs called 'Configuring Routes':

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#readme

The answer is also partially contained in the error message.

As to why devise_for seems to trump the route below that line in `routes.rb`, check out the Guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you
>   have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action’s
>   route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To
>   fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is
>   matched first.